# str.find() equivalent in java?

Tags: java, c++

Hi I'm trying to learn java so I'm converting my working c++ code to java. But I'm unsure about how to proceed with str.find(). Is there an equivalent of this in java? What I want to happen is I look for the first occurrence of a string in another string after the first comma not integer. I know of indexOf() and indexLastOf but they will only produce the fist and last occurrences.

```
void found() {
    int count = 1;
    size_t find = str.find(','); 
        while (find != string::npos) {
            count++;
            find = str.find(',', find + 1);
        }
     }
};
```

Comment: Use the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  You seek `indexOf` with an extra `int` argument.

Comment: indexOf - http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fjava%2Fjava_string_indexof.htm&ei=0UtqVKj8BIS0yAS_tYHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNFiQz60cf8NfeC7rHjF8k8E99Ra1g&sig2=_YR1DV3DysNQaAWWwvWRUA&bvm=bv.79142246,d.aWw

Comment: In addition to using 'indexOf', string::npos is defined in C++ as the integer constant -1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use str.indexOf('some string', indexToStartLooking); which will find the first occurrence of "some string" after the int in the second parameter and will return an int.

Comment: I don't want it to start looking after an integer. I want to to start looking after the first comma. Sorry I should have been more specific.I'll amend my question.

Comment: Then use `indexOf` without the extra argument first, to find the first comma; then whatever this returns, pass it to a subsequent call to `indexOf`.  It's exactly the same as what your C++ is doing, just with `indexOf` in place of `find`, and `-1` in place of `string::npos`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Java's Pattern and Matcher. Those classes involve regex pattern matching. It is very easy. Search here for other existing posts on that subject.